# Error during calling the python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am getting an error during calling a python class instance. 
I have the following code writen in my sublime, but when I run it I get the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/root/dog.py", line 17, in
>   
>       print(my_dog.age) AttributeError: Dog instance has no attribute 'age' [Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]

```
class Dog():

    def _init_(self, name, age):
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age

    def sit(self):
        print(self.name.title() + "is not sitting.")

    def roll_over(self):
        print(self.name.title() + "rolled over")

my_dog = Dog('Willie', 6)
print("My dog's name is " + my_dog.name.title() + ".")
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + "years old.")
my_dog.sit()
my_dog.roll_over()
print(my_dog.age)
```

Comment: You need double underscores each side of `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks for Daniel Roseman, for editing my question. I am new here. Dont know how to edit the page yet

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two underscores with the `__init__` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have added one more underscore and worked fine

Comment: @FarrukhSadykov, good to know, **but** next time you have a problem try to **google it first, look at sample code snippets and documentations** before asking questions. Just imagine, how much more database servers would stackoverflow need if every newbie, who couldn't write a constructor asked a question Good luck with your coding ;)